# Returning a new immediately excecuted function within an exported function

Tags: typescript

I can't get this to compile:

```
  export function Parse(jsonData) {
        try {
            if (jsonData.d != undefined) {
                if (jsonData.d != "") {
                    return (new function("return " + jsonData.d))();
                }
            }
            else {
                if (jsonData != "") {
                    return (new  function("return " + jsonData))();
                }
            }
            return {};
        }
        catch (e) {
            return { exception: e.Message };
        }
    }
```

It has a error marked under both **("return "** statements saying ) or } expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the whole in JavaScript it is best practice to avoid the `new` keyword. You can create the immediately executing anonymous functions without it, like this:

```
function Parse(jsonData) {
    try {
        if (typeof jsonData.d !== 'undefined') {
            if (jsonData.d != "") {
                    return (function(j) { 
                        return "return " + j.d;
                    }(jsonData));
                }
            } else {
                if (jsonData != "") {
                    return (function(j) { 
                        return "return " + j;
                    }(jsonData));
                }
            }
            return {};
        }
        catch (e) {
            return { exception: e.Message };
        }
}

var data = { d: 'x' }; // 'test';
var result = Parse(data);
alert(result);
```

In this example, I have removed the `new` keyword, passed the jsonData into the immediately executing function and added a `return` just so I could test the results.

Answer (score 0):

You want `new Function`, not `new function`, in both places there (same as in JavaScript).